# Kotlin Map with classes as keys?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I've got an interface `Vehicle` with implementations `Car`, `Motorcycle`, `Skateboard`, etc.

I would like to create a `Map` that contains attributes or data values for each implementation. A very simple one would look like:

```
val vehicleInfo : Map<KClass<Vehicle>, Map<String, String>> mapOf(
  Car::class to mapOf("wheels" to "4", "license_required" to "true"),
  Motorcycle::class to mapOf("wheels" to "2", "license_required" to "true"),
  Skateboard::class to mapOf("wheels" to "4", "license_required" to "false"),
)
```

but this won't compile due to `Type Mismatch` (between the `KClass` keys and `KClass<Vehicle>`)

(a similar possibility would be to use a data class for the map values: `data class(val wheels : Int, val license_required : Boolean)`)

Is there a way to create a Map with classes as the keys? Alternatively, is there a better pattern for creating a 1-1 mapping between classes and attributes (I don't want to say "properties" because, obviously, I could define these as properties in the interface and provide values in each class definition -- I specifically do NOT want to do that, I want to keep all the attributes together in its own Map or maybe some other data structure)... it seems like some functional programming concept or higher-order function might be applicable here. Thank you.

Comment: Side note. If all the "properties" of a vehicle are something you want to store outside the actual implementations, it seems like you shouldn't be using interfaces and classes at all. If Car, Motorcycle, and Skateboard have identical implementations, they should just be anonymous instances of Vehicle instead of concrete classes.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for the tip however they all have very different implementations for the interface's methods

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a covariant type for the KClass so any subtype of Vehicle can be used.

```
val vehicleInfo : Map<KClass<out Vehicle>, Map<String, String>> mapOf(
```

Comment: wow the `out` keyword made all the difference 

Comment: I have a map that is generated by groupBy. Is there a way to tell groupBy to output the correct map like state in this answer?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. You can omit the specified variable type and just let it infer the type. If there's ambiguity, you can specify it like this.